# What is the meaning of the phrase 'Information Junky'

Tags: word-meaning

I found this phrase in my computer book and now I want to know the meaning of the phrase 'Information Junky'. Please tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heh, that's a fun one.

"Junky" is just another way of spelling "[Junkie](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=junkie)", which refers to an addict (often a drug addict) compelled to take their addictive substance of choice.

So an information junkie is an addictive consumer of information, often someone who reads a lot on a topic to get more information before actually acting on that information.

Despite the connection in concept to a serious drug habit, the phrase is generally used in a *lighthearted* way and said *without* concern, as being an "Information Junkie" is almost always totally harmless.

Comment: Just to emphasize: this term does *not* have a negative connotation. I've mostly heard it in the context of people describing themselves. It's analogous to *chocoholic*.

Comment: @Era: Of *course* it has negative associations! But as often happens with "slangy" usages, you can deliberately override those connotations in sarcastic / facetious contexts.

Comment: *Junkie* has negative connotations, but *information junkie* does not.